# Atom plugin - trigger on window loaded

Tags: javascript, plugins, atom-editor

I've built a very simple plugin for atom which is able to load `.env` file variables into the Atom environment.

In the `activate` function of the plugin I trigger the function `this.myFunc()`, and before that I subscribe to `onDidChangePaths` with `atom.project.onDidChangePaths(this.myFunc)`.

`this.myFunc` (for semplicity) just sets some global variables like this: `process.env["MY_VAR"] = "MY_VAL"`. If I console log the env keys before and after, I see no difference.

It seems though that the `activate` function is being called before the process' environment is ready, because when I try to access MY_VAR in the console (via `console.log(MY_VAR)`) it returns `undefined` unless I manually call `this.myFunc()` again (after the loading).

I tried disabling all the other community plugins, thinking it was one of them resetting the environment variables, without any luck.

How can I let my plugin activate and "wait" for the global context to be ready? I don't find any documented way to do that.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on your init.coffee (Edit->config):

```js
atom.packages.onDidActivateInitialPackages ->
  workspaceView = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace)
  atom.commands.dispatch(workspaceView, 'my-package:init')
```

Comment: Hello netizen! Thanks for the response. Sorry for the late reply, but I think I resolved adding the same callback to `atom.whenShellEnvironmentLoaded`, `atom.workspace.onDidOpen`, `atom.project.onDidChangePaths`. Not sure though if there's a better way to handle them all in a common event